# How to import in Java

Tags: java, exception, import

I'm trying to import, and my statement looks like this:

```
import C.Users.pro-services.Documents.JAVA.libs.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
```

The compiler throws an error b/c of the hyphen in `pro-services`.  Is there an easy fix, or a deeper issue here(re: my understanding of import statements!)?

Thanks

Comment: So, I have to set the CLASSPATH to the absolute path, then I can just use an import statement like `com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed`, and it will be found in one of the files in the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my God, please tell me you're not referring to file's absolute path!
In Java, there is a thing called [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) which the Virtual Machine uses to locate classes.
Then, once your class is in the classpath (either in a jar file or inside your application), you can import it to your classes and use it.
The class you're trying to import seems to be [com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/rome/rome/0.9/rome-0.9-javadoc.jar!/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndFeed.html)
which you would import like:

```
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
```

That's considering you have it in your class-path. IF you don't, get the jar and put it in the classpath.

Comment: OK, you're exactly right.  So, I have to set the CLASSPATH to the absolute path, then I can just use an import statement like the one you suggest, and it will be found in one of the files in the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

the package pro-services is wrong. You can't create a package with hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `SyndFeed` on the [*classpath*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html), and refer to it by its fully-qualified name.

Roughly, the classpath contains of multiple jar files and individual class files. Each class (within or outside a .jar) has a fully-qualified name: the package name + the class name. That's what you write in your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `import` is not a path; it's the name of a Java package. At the top of `SyndFeed.java`, it should say something like

```
package feed.synd;
```

the argument to `package` should be the prefix for the class name in the `import`; i.e.,

```
import feed.synd.SyndFeed;
```

You don't use `import` to tell the compiler where to find the class; the `-classpath` switch (or, less nicely, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable) are used for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package for the `SyndFeed` class is `feed.synd`.  If this is the case, do the following:

1. `import feed.synd.SyndFeed;` in the java file.
2. If the `SyndFeed` class is in a jar, add the jar to the `classpath`.  Perhaps `CLASSPATH = C:\Users\pro-services\Documents\JAVA\libs\SyndFeedJarName.jar`.
3. If the `SyndFeed` class is not in a jar, add the directory that corresponds to the first name in the package (in this case, feed) to the classpath.  Perhaps `CLASSPATH = C:\Users\pro-services\Documents\JAVA\libs\feed`.